# I am trying find gcd in bash but in didn't work?

Tags: bash, recursion

```
Gcd () {
  if [ $2 -eq 0 ] 
   then 
    return $1
  fi
  return gcd($2,`expr $1 % $2`)
}
echo "Enter number"
read n1
read n2
Gcd n1 n2
value=$?
echo "GCD : $value"
```

I wrote this program and in Termux app but it shows err like

```
gcd.sh: 7: gcd.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

I re-written this program (filename : gcd1.sh)

```
gcd () {
 if [ "$2" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "$1"
 else
   gcd $2 $(( $1 % $2 ))
 fi
}

echo "Enter number"
read n1
read n2

gcd n1 n2
value=$?

echo "GCD : $value"
```

GCD program run with some error here is the output of program

```
Enter number
20
70
gcd1.sh: 2: [: Illegal number: n2
10
GCD : 0
```

Answer supposed to be

```
Enter number
20
70
GCD : 10
```

Comment: Put a shebang on your script and paste it to https://shellcheck.net

Comment: I would avoid recursion and use `while (( remainder > 0 )); do ...`.

Comment: @HalffunctionNobot : You have parentheses after your invocation of `gcd`. A pair of parenthesis creates a subshell. You can call it as `gcd $2 `expr $1 % $2`. And remove the _bash_ tag, because, as you can see from the wording of the error message, you are not running bash. Finally, the argument to `return` sets the **exit code** of a function. Hence using `gcd` after return does not make sense.

Comment: Your recursive function cannot work. The function is called `Gcd` while you reference it as `gcd` (capital)

Answer (score 0):

It's poor practice to use exit codes as a general integer value.  Return the integer value as a string using `stdout` (for instance using `echo`) instead.

After a few other minimal corrections, but still missing various error checks:

```
gcd () {
  if [ $2 -eq 0 ] 
   then 
    echo $1
  else
    echo $(gcd $2 `expr $1 % $2`)
  fi
}
```

Note the use of `$(gcd ...)` command substitution to call `gcd` recursively and capture its `stdout`, as `bash` treats the `gcd()` shell function like any other command.

Comment: You don't need the `echo $( )` part -- just run `gcd` directly, and let its output pass straight through to the outer context.

Comment: Using `$(($1 % $2))` instead of `expr` in a subshell is going to be way faster, btw.